# xHTML: region (div) in a table

Tags: xhtml, html-table

I have a table and I want to mark a region inside this table to insert Javascript for this region.
I need a div area inside the table, but XHTML 1.0 says, that I'm not allowed to do this.

My table looks like this:

```
<table>
  <caption><p>...</p></caption>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and I need something like that:

```
<table>
  <caption><p>...</p></caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    <!-- region start e.g. <div class="myRegionInsideTR">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>10</td>
        region end </div> -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I want to do e.g.

```
$(".myRegionInsideTR").attr("noSense", true).css("display", "none");
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a colgroup:

```
<table>
  <caption><p>...</p></caption>
    <colgroup><col span="2"></col><col span="2" class="democol"></col></colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>

        <td>3</td>
        <td>10</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vMKgC/

Note that for whatever reason, this fiddle doesn't work in Chrome, but does work in firefox.

Answer (score -2):

Switch away from xhtml, it's strictness brings in restrictions like this.

Because  is part of a table only tabular data is allowed to be shown, you should look at your design and see if tables are the way to go for your solution.

Although according this site:
http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/td/#td-contains
or 
http://www.december.com/html/x1/element/td.html
the contents of a TD should be block or inline elements, which makes DIV perfectly legal.

Comment: The div would be a content of a tr, not a td.

Comment: If you mean "did I read the question and understand it", then yes, I did. Your response does not answer the question, suggesting that you did not.